# Node.JS impossible to install ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, ionic-framework

I've recently installed Node.JS for ionic framework. But when i type on the terminal :

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

I've got this error :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/TARRADOUJL/npm-debug.log
```

During the installation of Node.JS I need to make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

And when i type

```
$PATH
```

The results is :

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

I'm not a "Pro" with the line commands.. but i think i need to change my $PATH for install ionic right ? In this case ? How can i do please?

Comment: Looks like you have to launch your terminal with admin rights

Comment: There's an error which actually tells you what to try: "npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." Matu's answer seems to cover this. Next time try to read what the error says :)

Comment: Thank you :) but Now i've got 5 npm WARN engine :/

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo npm install -g cordova`. You may have to input your password.

Comment: I have 'npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.0.0","npm":"2.14.2"})'

Comment: You could try to run it with older node version. Atleast the error seems to say that